# What does # sign mean in C?

Tags: c

I have come across this code and I am not sure what `#reg`is doing:

```
#define FPGA_WRITE(reg,val) do { printf("%-20s %08X <<- %08lX\n", #reg, (reg), (unsigned long)(val));} while (0)

int main()
{
   FPGA_WRITE(10,15);
   return 0;
}
```

This prints this following:

```
10                   0000000A <<- 0000000F
```

If I take out the `#`, I get a segfault when I execute the code. Strange. What is the usage of `#`?

Comment: It "stringizes" the token. In your example `FPGA_WRITE(10, 15)` becomes after preprocessing `do { printf("...", "10", (10), ...); } while (0)`

Comment: And *without* the stringification, you're trying to printf the `int` value 10 as if it were a `char*`, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: I assume you're not talking about the one in `#define`?

Comment: Note: it only works on the preprocessing stage. `int a = 42; char v[] = #a /* not "42"! Error! */;`

Comment: To be fair to the asker, it's hard to do a Web search for a punctuation mark.  And, being a preprocessor rather than "language" feature, `#` is not often mentioned in tables of C "operators".

Comment: Can this question be in faq?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is [Stringizing Operator (#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) used inside `#define` pre-processor macros,

which turns the argument it precedes into a quoted string